# Django collectstatic result in S3ResponseError: 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm running a Django project that is adding all static and media files to Amazon S3. I'm using a settings.py configuration that I've used many times in the past and that work for multiple other projects (Posted below).

When I use the same settings.py file on my own localhost. I can run `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` fine and it will upload all static files to Amazon S3. But when I put my project on an Elastic Beanstalk Application server and run the same command, with the same settings, I get `S3ResponseError: 301 Moved Permanently`.

My settings are:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 's3.cupcard.com'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = 'boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat'
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL = 'http:'  # Replace with 'https:' if you're not using http.

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = "http://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'lindshop.utils.custom_storages.CachedS3BotoStorage'

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "http://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'lindshop.utils.custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

The `lindshop.utils.custom_storages.CachedS3BotoStorage` looks like this:

```
class EuropeConnection(S3Connection):
    DefaultHost = "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"

class CachedS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    connection_class = EuropeConnection
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_storage = get_storage_class(
            "compressor.storage.CompressorFileStorage")()

    def save(self, name, content):
        non_gzipped_file_content = content.file
        name = super(CachedS3BotoStorage, self).save(name, content)
        content.file = non_gzipped_file_content
        self.local_storage._save(name, content)
        return name
```

To summarize and to repeat myself.

1. I can run `python manage.py collectstatic` from localhost. I've also validated that I can access the files on the S3 instance that the localhost has put up there with the `collectstatic`command. When I do the same from a Elastic Beanstalk Application with the same settings, I get error.
2. I've used the same settings in other projects before without problems. Only thing changed is the bucket name.
3. The error I get when I run `collectstatic` on the EB-server is `S3ResponseError: 301 Moved Permanently`.

Full Traceback:

```
caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
  management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 176, in handle
  collected = self.collect()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 107, in collect
  handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 325, in copy_file
  if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 238, in delete_file
  if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 446, in exists
  return k.exists()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 539, in exists
  return bool(self.bucket.lookup(self.name, headers=headers))
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 143, in lookup
  return self.get_key(key_name, headers=headers)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 193, in get_key
  key, resp = self._get_key_internal(key_name, headers, query_args_l)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 231, in _get_key_internal
  response.status, response.reason, '')
  boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 301 Moved Permanently

   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

Comment: Please update your question and post the complete traceback.

Comment: Is this bucket outside the US region?

Comment: Yes it's created in eu-west-1. That's why its using a connection class with `DefaultHost = "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"`

Comment: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/443 - I believe you are running into this.

Comment: Could it be something that when I'm on localhost it uses no IAM to connect to S3, but when I'm on elastic beanstalk it uses a default ec2-user IAM?

Do I need to add some permissions to the IAM to be able to upload/see S3?

Comment: That's why I'm using `OrdinaryCallingFormat()`. Remember, this settings have worked fine for multiple projects (all using EU or Asian S3 endpoints) for years.

Comment: I don't think this is IAM issue, otherwise you would get a different error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that the problem is because an update to the Django module `django-storages` that I used. In the update they have added a default value to `S3BotoStorage.host` by assigning it in the following way:

```
host = setting('AWS_S3_HOST', S3Connection.DefaultHost)
```

What happens is that the host is automatically set to `s3.amazonaws.com` and because it already have a host set when it creates the connection with `boto` (AWS official python-package), it never uses the `DefaultHost = "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"` that I added in my `EuropeConnection`-class.

The way to solve this problem is to set django-storages settings value `AWS_S3_HOST` (New) in your `settings.py`.

```
AWS_S3_HOST = "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
```